# how to specify only the named curve in CSR request?

Tags: openssl

I am trying to send a CSR to a server and it is successfully signed when generated from the command line but fails with a (0 length ASN.1) error when generated programatically. I suspect, perhaps, its the long form of the curve params, but wont know until/if I can remove them from the one generted programatically. How can I only specify the ASN1 OID: secp521r1?

Heres the commandline version:

```
openssl ecparam -out ec521.pem -name secp521r1 -genkey
openssl req -new  -days 3652  -key ec521.pem  -out ec.csr -outform DER
openssl req -in ec.csr -text -inform DER


Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 0 (0x0)
        Subject: CN=305419896
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (521 bit)
                pub: 
                    04:00:e3:5d:87:42:16:da:ff:6b:10:35:dc:6a:84:
                    0b:78:5b:4b:d5:df:3b:fc:aa:01:d7:a6:39:57:11:
                    45:4c:9b:45:8e:15:64:c8:61:76:05:a2:cf:c6:e7:
                    23:06:00:a9:b3:a8:88:95:e4:ee:fe:e0:40:d8:d4:
                    9a:50:51:6f:01:2a:af:00:09:37:78:b4:ef:66:08:
                    81:87:19:7d:f4:1b:c7:74:49:cb:ee:bd:21:23:a4:
                    3b:48:a7:6f:f5:aa:d3:cb:31:38:15:2c:d1:ff:96:
                    57:a8:3c:5b:21:27:44:c1:88:0d:df:f9:0f:e2:43:
                    41:94:f2:63:bb:23:b4:e3:98:a3:62:4f:e5
                ASN1 OID: secp521r1
        Attributes:
            a0:00
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA1
         30:81:87:02:41:04:41:99:91:31:dc:5a:6b:0a:b3:e3:01:c3:
         9a:d5:1a:aa:46:74:8c:09:da:22:60:41:41:df:8e:03:ee:81:
         a4:0b:e6:0a:de:b0:fd:9a:8b:c1:3c:79:5f:f8:87:9a:dd:38:
         6b:e4:4f:eb:3c:a4:9a:d1:6b:a7:a8:4f:a0:94:f0:c3:02:42:
         01:48:e2:6b:f1:fe:9f:3e:2e:d1:2d:65:d9:ea:e0:4e:1c:e5:
         f1:4d:49:f3:f0:a9:e8:e9:7a:ff:70:98:b5:e0:20:47:c6:b8:
         62:75:e9:59:51:64:96:de:eb:2b:bd:30:60:75:09:c5:4c:bb:
         f1:64:c6:c0:87:50:fd:57:91:af:72:29
```

Heres the programatic version:

```
openssl req -in tempcsr.der -text -inform DER
Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 0 (0x0)
        Subject: CN=305419896
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (521 bit)
                pub: 
                    04:00:8f:e8:63:df:83:55:55:34:4d:ec:6b:d8:78:
                    1d:e8:03:65:48:26:3d:1c:1f:da:2a:ed:d9:2d:d5:
                    ed:23:e7:d2:d1:2a:b0:fb:47:57:74:8a:24:8f:0b:
                    81:b7:47:ad:5a:86:73:24:c7:3d:0d:d2:40:42:34:
                    b6:2f:b6:55:3b:a5:15:01:91:71:ca:9f:23:83:a4:
                    27:60:ed:45:ae:44:5c:aa:7c:3f:89:fb:25:68:21:
                    1b:c5:c6:b6:db:d1:59:44:5c:ef:90:b2:84:e2:a7:
                    38:d6:a2:51:02:6a:99:a8:ac:51:64:e6:ff:09:84:
                    9a:25:71:ba:ce:51:13:1c:d7:a5:41:f0:be
                Field Type: prime-field
                Prime:
                    01:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
                    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
                    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
                    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
                    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
                A:   
                    01:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
                    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
                    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
                    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
                    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:fc
                B:   
                    51:95:3e:b9:61:8e:1c:9a:1f:92:9a:21:a0:b6:85:
                    40:ee:a2:da:72:5b:99:b3:15:f3:b8:b4:89:91:8e:
                    f1:09:e1:56:19:39:51:ec:7e:93:7b:16:52:c0:bd:
                    3b:b1:bf:07:35:73:df:88:3d:2c:34:f1:ef:45:1f:
                    d4:6b:50:3f:00
                Generator (uncompressed):
                    04:00:c6:85:8e:06:b7:04:04:e9:cd:9e:3e:cb:66:
                    23:95:b4:42:9c:64:81:39:05:3f:b5:21:f8:28:af:
                    60:6b:4d:3d:ba:a1:4b:5e:77:ef:e7:59:28:fe:1d:
                    c1:27:a2:ff:a8:de:33:48:b3:c1:85:6a:42:9b:f9:
                    7e:7e:31:c2:e5:bd:66:01:18:39:29:6a:78:9a:3b:
                    c0:04:5c:8a:5f:b4:2c:7d:1b:d9:98:f5:44:49:57:
                    9b:44:68:17:af:bd:17:27:3e:66:2c:97:ee:72:99:
                    5e:f4:26:40:c5:50:b9:01:3f:ad:07:61:35:3c:70:
                    86:a2:72:c2:40:88:be:94:76:9f:d1:66:50
                Order: 
                    01:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
                    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
                    ff:ff:ff:fa:51:86:87:83:bf:2f:96:6b:7f:cc:01:
                    48:f7:09:a5:d0:3b:b5:c9:b8:89:9c:47:ae:bb:6f:
                    b7:1e:91:38:64:09
                Cofactor:  1 (0x1)
                Seed:
                    d0:9e:88:00:29:1c:b8:53:96:cc:67:17:39:32:84:
                    aa:a0:da:64:ba
        Attributes:
            a0:00
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA1
         30:81:88:02:42:00:b6:d9:11:7b:ff:db:70:e8:a5:f3:3f:67:
         99:1d:97:5e:ae:ed:7e:dc:c4:c7:5b:0e:79:6a:b5:67:23:f8:
         bb:f2:0e:9e:4b:df:43:41:dc:cb:e5:99:00:6e:a4:7e:9c:fe:
         48:3e:8c:97:36:c7:b6:5d:55:4e:f8:2c:8a:c3:ca:b8:47:02:
         42:00:a9:2d:01:58:bc:21:df:88:6b:cb:ba:f3:fc:b9:06:6b:
         9e:1d:31:d5:07:5b:a1:46:51:4c:99:48:38:41:ab:59:1e:55:
         1e:9d:6b:73:23:ee:e9:74:3b:da:97:73:9e:b5:b8:be:23:ef:
         45:6c:61:30:31:61:a9:93:50:7b:cb:82:4d
```

generated as such:

```
EVP_PKEY *privkey;

    if ((privkey = EVP_PKEY_new()) == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot allocate memory for private key.\n");
        finssl();
        exit(1);
    }

    EC_KEY *eckey;


    printf("Generating ECC keypair...\n");
    eckey = EC_KEY_new();
    if (NULL == eckey) {
        printf("Failed to create new EC Key\n");
        return -1;
    }

    EC_GROUP *ecgroup = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp521r1);
    if (NULL == ecgroup) {
        printf("Failed to create new EC Group\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int set_group_status = EC_KEY_set_group(eckey, ecgroup);
    const int set_group_success = 1;
    if (set_group_success != set_group_status) {
        printf("Failed to set group for EC Key\n");
        return -1;
    }


    if (!EC_KEY_generate_key(eckey)) {
        printf("Failed to generate EC Key\n");
        finssl();
        exit(1);
    }

    if (!EVP_PKEY_assign_EC_KEY(privkey, eckey)) {
        printf("Cannot assign keypair to private key.\n");
        finssl();
        exit(1);
    }

    X509_REQ *req;
    if ((req = X509_REQ_new()) == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot allocate memory for certificate request.\n");
        finssl();
        exit(1);
    }

    X509_NAME * name;
    name = X509_REQ_get_subject_name(req);
    X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(name, "CN", MBSTRING_ASC, (unsigned char *)"305419896", -1, -1, 0);

    X509_REQ_set_pubkey(req, privkey);
    if (!X509_REQ_sign(req, privkey, EVP_ecdsa())) {
        printf("Cannot sign request.\n");
        finssl();
        exit(1);
    }



    const char *keyfn = "tempkey.der";
    const char *csrfn = "tempcsr.der";
    // write to files ...
    FILE * f;
    f = fopen(keyfn, "w");

    i2d_PrivateKey_fp(f, privkey);

    fclose(f);
    f = fopen(csrfn, "w");
    i2d_X509_REQ_fp(f, req);
    fclose(f);
```

Comment: int  asn1_flag = OPENSSL_EC_NAMED_CURVE;EC_GROUP_set_asn1_flag(ecgroup, asn1_flag);

Answer (score 1):

you can specify only the curve name (OID) in the CSR by the following:

int asn1_flag = OPENSSL_EC_NAMED_CURVE;
EC_GROUP_set_asn1_flag(ecgroup, asn1_flag);

But that wasn't my problem. It's strange, but I needed to explicitly set the version:

509_REQ_set_version(req,0L)

Even though the version seemed to default to 0x0 anyhow ...

Answer (score 0):

You found the right answer for using the 'named' key form (OID for the curve instead of 'explicit' prime, a, b, G etc).

openssl should indeed be able to *create* a CSR, or/and a cert, for an explicit ECC key; I don't know why you were getting '0 length ASN.1' and agree it makes no sense redundantly setting version would matter. But an SSL server can *use* an explicit ECC key&cert only if the client's supported_curves list includes the special codes FF01 or FF02 as applicable, and no client I know of does so. For actual interoperation, best to use the named form. And probably better to stick with P-256 (aka prime256v1 in openssl) which seems to be the most popular.

This problem (TLS session not negotiated at all, or not using ECC suites, because of explicit form ECC) has come up several times on the openssl mailinglists, most recently about two weeks ago.

Small aside: if you or anyone ever wants to use your code on Windows, DER files are binary and must be fopen'ed in C using modifier "b".